# Let $M$ be a non-empty set whose elements are sets. What are $F=\{A×\{A\} : A⊆M, A≠∅\}$ and $⋃F$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think it's not so difficult but I struggling a little to figure it out, I want to make sure I'm correct, is $F$ a set of the form:
$F=\{ \{(a, A), (b, A), …\}, \{(α, B), (β, B), …\}, ...\}$ for all $a,b,...∈A$ and $α,β,...∈B$, where $A,B,...⊆M$?

and $⋃F$ a set of the form: 
$⋃F=\{(a, A), (b, A), …,(α, B), (β, B), …\}$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y$ is an element of $F$ iff it has the shape $y=A\times\{A\}$ where $A\subseteq M$ and $A\neq\varnothing$.

The equality in your title already states this and cannot essentially be improved, so you do not have to bother about $F$ itself.

$x$ is an element of $\bigcup F$ iff $x\in y$ for some $y\in F$.

Referring to the first line we get:

$x$ is an element of $\bigcup F$ iff $x\in A\times\{A\}$ for some $A$ with $A\subseteq M$ and $A\neq\varnothing$.

That means that $x$ must have the shape $x=(a,A)$ where $a\in A$.

Proved is now that:$$\bigcup F=\{(a,A)\mid a\in A\subseteq M\}$$
The condition $A\neq\varnothing$ does not need to be mentioned here because $a\in A$ *implies* that $A\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Yeah, so what i wrote is correct right?

Comment: Let's say that the idea is correct. A rigorous notation of $\bigcup F$ answering all questions lacks.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to understand intuitively what those sets looked like

Comment: You are welcome.